# MySQL :: Edge Case :: Mixed Type Foreign Key :: Possible or Dreaming?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, constraints

Got an edge case that I'm hoping to resolve.

We run a sport report that records, among other stats, box score results which may involve a non-league/non-roster opponent.  By this I mean that in some cases Foo opponent does not have a roster (nor will they ever) in our system.

Rather than simply omitting any stats for the opponent team, the owner requested long ago that we build-in the option to allow typed in player names (vs. selecting [playerID] from dropdown list of player names for an existing roster).  So, our roster table has an int playerID PK column, but our stats tables (offense & defense) have varchar playerID columns.

This allows us to do an outer join on the roster table and get matching records whether a team roster exists or not (if not we simply print out the varchar stat table playerID as the player's name).  Hacked for sure, but does the job.

Now, I have an FK on the results table to the stats table, so if a game result is deleted, related stats are as well.  However, we're missing an important constraint: roster >> stats. Since the playerID column types do not match, I am unable to add the FK I need to fill in the constraints gap (i.e. delete a player from roster and all of his/her stats will be orphaned, not good).

Any ideas for how to work around this?

Comment: Use a trigger to force the cascade delete.

Comment: +1 @Denis, yes, or deal with it at middleware layer. Trying to integrate with an ORM, however, so was hoping to be able to define the constraint in middleware and have it applied in MySQL.

Comment: I'd use a trigger for that, myself. Or rework the model a bit with an intermediary table if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience is that this is a problem that occurs to developers, but doesn't usually come up much in practice.

Is deleting players an actual use case?  Does the user want to go back to look at a game and not see a 'historic' player name?

I would recommended two changes:

1. Mark players inactive, then you can display them with some kind of
   inactive flag by their name, instead of deleting.
2. Add a StatsPlayerName column to the stats table, and move all of the "text" player names into it from the playerID column.  Then, a stat should have either a playerID or a StatPlayerName.  Now, you can do your join and if RosterPlayerName is null, then show StatsPlayerName.  This will let you add your foreign key constraint on playerID.

Comment: meh, changed my approach since posting this last year, now all stat entries must have a roster entry, so the foreign key issue is resolved as well as performing straight, efficient queries (no need for outer join or if null condition)...saying that, an answer is an answer, even months after the fact, so you get the check mark, decent enough feedback